# Types of dynamic types in Groovy

Tags: json, grails, groovy

**Main question:** What operators, properties, etc. can be used to determine the type of variables in Groovy?

Background:

I have an arbitrarily deeply-nested dictionary data structure. It is the result of calling `request.JSON` in a Grails controller. I would first like to verify certain keys are in the dictionary, with the appropriate types. The way I would like to implement this is by creating a prototypical data structure and defining a method to compare data structures. Something like:

```
def prototype = [ username: "JennyJeans",
                   message: [ subject: "Hello World!",
                                 body: "Will write soon."
                            ]
                 ]
```

Of course, the content of the Strings here doesn't matter. Then, in my actions, I validate like this:

```
if(similarDataStructure(prototype, request.JSON)) {
// XXX
} else {
 // report error
}
```

So, what does the `similarDataStructure` method do? In pseudocode:

```
def similarDataStructure(a, b) {
  if(type(a) != type(b)) return false

  if(type(a) == dictionary) {
    for key in a:
      if(!similarDataStructure(a[key], b[key])) return false
  }

  return true
}
```

If you can think of a better way to do deep validation, let me know.

Comment: On further thought, I've discovered what I am really trying to implement is a JSON schema validator for Grails

Answer (score 1):

To obtain types, you can use a.class, b.class and compare them: `if(a.class == b.class) { }`

To check if it's a dictionary, you can call: `a instanceof Map`.

However, try the following code in Groovy console to see it yourself ;-)

```
def src = [ username: "JennyJeans",
           message: [ subject: "Hello World!",
                      body: "Will write soon."]
         ]

def p1 = [ username: "JennyJeans",
           message: [ subject: "Hello World!",
                      body: "Will write soon."]
         ]

def p2 = [ username: "JennyJeans",
           message: [ subject: "Hello World!",
                      body: "Will read soon."]
         ]

println src == p1
println src == p2
```